# I think that is always a healthy thing to have collaborators. (???)

Tags: grammar, infinitives

First, could you have a look at the quote below, focusing on the highlighted portion?

> I am forced to think in a very different kind of way because I am collaborating, and **I think that is always a healthy thing to have collaborators**. — [Transcript from an interview with Kazuo Ishiguro,  Nobel Laureate in Literature 2017](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/literature/2017/ishiguro/158991-kazuo-ishiguro-interview-transcript/)

There's also a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BcJCybfdKg&t=51s) of the interview itself

Here's my question: What does the highlighted portion mean? From an English learner's view, there may be two ways of interpreting it:

1. I think that that (ie, to think in a different kind of way) is a healthy thing in order to have collaborators.
2. I think that it's a healthy thing to have collaborators. (Meaning: I suppose that to have collaborators is a healthy thing. And the word "is" in the original should be a typo for "it's.")

I have a gut feeling that option 2 is correct. I believe that option 1 is incorrect because the construction "something is a healthy thing to do something else" (intended to mean "something is a healthy thing in order to do something else") is impossible.

Am I correct? Or can there be a third option? Thank you very much for your attention. Your dedicated attention and beautiful enlightenment always fascinate me.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147975/discussion-on-question-by-the-oed-loves-me-not-i-think-that-is-always-a-healthy); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Don't over think it.  It means just having collaborators to work with is healthy and productive.

The grammar cops would probably prefer something like

> And, I think having collaborators is healthy.

This is not formally written at all.  Maybe from a blog, reddit post or SE The Workplace.  Perfectly fine for conversational English.

Comment: I agree. My own answer explains more of the details; this is nicely concise.

Answer (score 1):

You could interpret this as a kind of cleft sentence.  Normally you could have

> It is a healthy thing to have collaborators.

Hence you could say

> I think it is a healthy thing to have collaborators.

And you could say "I think that it is a healthy thing..."

So all that has happened here is that the two construction have merged. The resulting mess is not correct, but hardly noticeable (it doesn't affect understanding)

I can't fit your first meaning to this sentence. I'm sure that meaning is not intended, and this is a simple typo.  While infintives can give a purpose (often this can be express with "in order to") it would not be possible to read the sentence as

> I think "being forced to think in a different way" is a good thing, in order to have collaborators.

I just don't see the connection. I just doesn't work, when there is a much more natural interpretion.

Whereas it probably would be possible to say

> Cooking is a good thing, in order to please your spouse.

But it's not a very natural way to express this idea.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your careful follow-up. Now, in connection with the sub-question I was asking just now, is it possible for a native speaker to write something like this? -- Cooking is a good thing to please your spouse. --- I was thinking that this sentence in this construction doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your further follow-up about "Cooking is a good thing, in order to please your spouse." That's exactly what I wanted a native speaker to confirm. I'm relieved to have got your input.

Comment: If this has solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the green tick.

Comment: I don't think *Cooking is a good thing, in order to please your spouse* is remotely idiomatic. What we would say is, for example, *Cooking is a good **way** to please your spouse.*

Answer (score -3):

## Collaborating is healthy; no typo

It's somewhat advanced grammar, strange to some, but very correct. A comma for the last clause would be best, though.

### Affectionate

This is a good example of the [affectionate use of the demonstrative](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/545847/315731) *that*. While the antecedent is explained before, *that* is further clarified in the later clause "to have collaborators".

From [Explaining variance in writers' use of demonstratives: A corpus study demonstrating the importance of discourse genre](https://www.glossa-journal.org/article/id/5826/):

> The idea of proximal demonstratives expressing the (positive) involvement of the writer vs. distal demonstratives expressing the (negative) backside can be found in many proposals...
>
> ...or to be associated with affection, interest, and pride, as opposed to contempt, disapproval, dislike, and mental remoteness.

While that article calls them proximal (positive) and distal (negative), my study with Greek refers to the *positive* as affectionate and the negative as *contemptuous*.

Example of affectionate use of a demonstrative:

> Oh, I love **that** guy!

Example of contemptuous use of a demonstrative:

> Oh, I hate **that** teacher!

By using the word *that*, the contempt or affection is emphasized.

That is what I know and use in my own work with writing and my college major, which was ancient Greek being translated into English. I often explain this to many of my ESL students, which I have experience in for 13 years.

As for the phrase in the question, we could rephrase it as such, using punctuation for clarity:

> I think that is a healthy thing (to have collaborators).

Equally, we can say:

> I think that is a healthy thing.

More importantly, using demonstrative pronouns (this, that, these, those) can indicate *affection* or *contempt*, among other things, all depending on the context. In this situation, the writer is talking well (*affectionately*) of collaboration, so we would not be wrong to say this is an "affectionate use of the demonstrative".

### Anaphoric

But, the use of the demonstrative is more than merely for affection. It also refers to much of the previous explanation, being that it is an [anaphoric demonstrative](https://www.rit.edu/ntid/sea/processes/referencewords/practice/phoric.) (commonly the far demonstrative: that, those), as opposed to cataphoric, referring to something explained *later on* (more commonly the near demonstrative: this, these).

Rephrased:

> I think [all **that** I just explained] is a healthy thing (to have collaborators).

If we wanted to improve this, we could argue that it is missing a comma to separate that last parenthetical phrase, meaning we could arrive at this:

> I think that is a healthy thing, to have collaborators.

### Tip for learners

While learning English as a second language, be cautious of the notion that all sentences must fit into common patterns such as "I think it is". That phrase is common, but not always necessary. "I think that is" also can be proper grammar.

In the phrase used, we have proper use of subjects, verbs, and objects. The writer uses "that" as part of either clear writing or good conversation, linking the ideas in the last sentence to other ideas already explained.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "affectionate" demonstrative, and your link attached to that word-pair is nothing to do with the syntactic category *(this, that, these, those)* anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- Thank you for your further input. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Jesse --- Thank you for your input. I'm now wondering how you would react to FumbleFinger's comment.

Comment: Anaphor is just a fancy word for describing that a referent occurs previously in the sentence or paragraph.  It is present here, but that has nothing to do with the grammar mistake in the original example.  There's no need to confuse learners with the term.

Comment: @TheOEDLovesMeNot I added a citation with examples. Sorry to make such a bold statement, but FF is factually in error. This is what my college major was in and I studied two years under a renowned scholar as my professor. Moreover, ESL is a significant part of my work. You can trust my explanation of what's going on here.

Comment: @BadZen I won't claim whether it is a mistake or not because we'd need to ask the writer to know for sure. But, if it was a mistake, then it was a mistake with perfect spelling, advanced grammar, and rich meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers perhaps you would accept it if it were called an "affectionate *use* of the demonstrative". Surely you are familiar with this in some manner or another.

Comment: The highlighted part of OP is not grammatical, @Jesse.  See Mari-Lou's answer for details, it's in every way correct.

Comment: You seem to be confusing two denotations of "demonstrative", by the way.   One is a technical term of grammar, the other is a rough synonym of "affectionate".  These are definitions (2) and (3) respectively in Merriam Webster:  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demonstrative

Comment: No. I think the entire *concept* of "affectionate" is irrelevant to demonstrative pronouns. Perhaps this is some kind of terminological issue. The collocation "affectionate demonstratives" (plural) doesn't occur even once in Google Books, and I'm quite sure all the matches for singular "affectionate demonstrative"  will be about *people* who have an "affectionate, demonstrative ***personality*** - nothing to do with grammar and syntax.

Comment: @BadZen The question isn't about spelling; I think it is fair to address grammar here. Yes, Mari-Lou has a great answer, and if you look at my final version in the last edit, you should see that I'm driving at a similar idea. And, I do have an original edit quote that suggests the same sentence she does, leaving off the "collaborator" phrase at the end.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *I think*. *Google Books*. Near and far demonstratives, both singular and plural can be used to describe affection and contempt; yes, they can. Go see how many times "that man" is used to like or hate the man in Google Books.

Comment: I don't want to respond more except to the OP @TheOEDLovesMeNot. I mod elsewhere and this has been good and is good enough.

Comment: I think it's pointless to say *I love **this** but I hate **that*** is something to do with "affectionate / contemptuous demonstratives". You might as well say *I love **him** but I hate **her*** involves "affectionate / contemptuous pronouns". That's just nonsense.